# Suggestion for AJAX/live edit of a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, edit

I'm looking for a library for live editing of HTML Tables (AJAX submit). I have forms for adding the records, but the thing is, I'm too lazy to create additional forms (or reuse the add forms with additional parameters) for everything that needs to be edited, and also there are no complicated calculations on the data that is presented in the table, so basically is just an output from one (or a few) database tables.

I searched for this kind of libraries, but almost all of the libraries are 2-3 years old, so I'm not really sure of using them, because of the advancement in the browsers.

I'm working at the moment in PHP, and I'm using jQuery, (so better if it is a plugin for it), not that it matters a lot. I don't mind using some other big library instead (Prototype, Mootools, ExtJS).

I'm open to suggestions on server-side (combined) too, if it is better.

So the options I checked so far (not tried, just browsed) are:

- [TableKit](http://millstream.com.au/view/code/tablekit/), using Prototype, last update july, 2008
- [tableEditor](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/tableEditor/demo.php), recomends using jQuery 1.0.3
- [phpMyEdit](http://www.phpmyedit.org/), last update around 2009, server-side, but sends the params that need to be edited through GET, and I need to edit textareas also
- [MySQLAJAXTableEditor](http://www.mysqlajaxtableeditor.com), server-side, looks good, not sure about it
- [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable), edits everything, not only tables, last update 2009
- [SmartGrid](http://www.richarea.com/demo/smart_grid/), looks very old

So, anyone had experience with this kind of stuff, pros/cons of live edit, and any suggestion of a library?

Comment: A comment just for future references:
I modified TableKit (mixing together Prototype and jQuery), and it was pretty fine for using.

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid is good, full featured, and gets frequent updates: http://www.trirand.com/blog/